# Исправить ошибку Access violation WinApi

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

Есть код на C# для запуска EXE прямо в ОЗУ без распаковки на жесткий диск. Использую функции WinApi. Не получается запустить поток, программа падает и выдает ошибку Access violation.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace Program
{

    internal class Program
    {
        public enum TYPE
        {
            MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000,
            MEM_RESERVE = 0x00002000
        }

        public enum PROTECTION
        {
            PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] exe = Resource1.ExeProg;
            int exesize = exe.Length;
            IntPtr buf = VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, (UInt32)exesize, (UInt32)TYPE.MEM_COMMIT, (UInt32)PROTECTION.PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
            if (buf == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("VirtualAlloc error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                return;
            }
            Marshal.Copy(exe, 0, buf, exesize);
            uint dummy;
            bool flag = VirtualProtect(buf, exesize, (UInt32)PROTECTION.PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, out dummy);
            uint threadId = 0;
            IntPtr hThread = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr pinfo = IntPtr.Zero;
            hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, buf, pinfo, 0, ref threadId);
            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        }
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr hHandle, uint dwMilliseconds);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateThread(
            uint lpThreadAttributes,
            uint dwStackSize,
            IntPtr lpStartAddress,
            IntPtr param,
            uint dwCreationFlags,
            ref uint lpThreadId);
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        public static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern bool VirtualProtect(IntPtr lpAddress, int dwSize, uint flNewProtect, out uint lpflOldProtect);

    }
}
```

Где ошибка? Как правильно запустить поток?

Comment: Если просто зашить в память процесса образ (содержимое exe), то ничего запустить не получится, так как создание процесса - это более сложный процесс (можно у руссиновича почитать). Если надо внешнюю программу запустить, то сделайте ее в виде DLL и штатными средствами подгрузите. Если пытаетесь в хакерство поиграть, то msfvenom умеет генерировать массив для c#, который можно так, как у вас в коде, запустить.

Comment: Как понять штатными средствами в виде DLL? Можете привести пример

Comment: Компилируете свой exe-шник (который ExeProg) как DLL-библиотеку (это же ваш код?), а потом в данной программе вызывать `Assembly.LoadFile`, примерно так.

Comment: Что мешает распаковать на диск во временный файл, и потом запустить? Зачем это всё? Ну если только это не вредоносный код. А так, dll и сборка в единый файл, для старого фреймворка ILMerge есть, без костылей с ресурсами.